# Multiple method can use under one condition?

Tags: c#

i write some code in `c#` for example ;

```
 if(Condition)

 {
   private void ribbonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Do something ; 
    }

 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       Do Something ;
      }
 private void ribbonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Do something ; 
    }

}
```

Is this allowed ?  can we restrict multiple Methods of control under any condition ? Not only if can we use any Loop?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't actually do that.

Comment: The compiler would have caught this error...

Answer (score 1):

do this instead

```
 private void ribbonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (condition)
       {
         Do something ; 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes we can do that but what if i want to restrict some methods ?

Comment: Make a public bool , set it if the condition is true , then check if that bool is true in each method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict a specific method. But what you can do is call the method in a specific condition.

```
public bool Condition;

private void ribbonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Condition) ThingsYouWantToDo();
}

private void ThingsYouWantToD()
{
//Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ribbonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Condition)
        DoFirstStuff();
    else if (Condition2)
        DoSecondStuff();
    else
        DoThirdStuff();
}
```

But wait... are you maybe speaking about conditional compiler directives? Like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    #if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("You are running debug version!");
    #endif

    Console.WriteLine("Program is starting!");
}
```